# Stability of syzygy bundles of smooth curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, syzygies

For a very ample line bundle $L$, the kernel of the surjection $H^0(L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow L \rightarrow 0$ is denoted by $M_L$ and is called syzygy bundle. In this [paper](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/robert.lazarsfeld/Reprints/Ein.Laz.Mustopa.Stab.Syz.Bund.Alg.Sf.pdf) authors claim in the first page that stability of $M_L$ is well-known for smooth curves given the degree of $L$ is large enough.

Edit: Over finite fields, is it known when or for which curves, $M_L$ becomes strongly semi-stable? (A trivial example would be elliptic curves, since on elliptic curves semi-stability implies strong semi-stability)

Comment: I haven't checked all the references given in the paper you mention, but for instance Proposition 1 of [1] gives exactly what you ask (in fact, for $\deg L\geq 2g+1$). I am pretty sure the other references work as well.

Comment: Yes thanks. I saw this, especially the first theorem basically says $M_L$ is stable but under the assumption of being non-hyperelliptic, which I think is present throughout the whole paper. I think the statement above does not depend on hyper-ellipticity.

Comment: OK, then Theorem 1.3 in [4] does the job.

Comment: This one is definitely better. But again has the assumption $g\geq 2$. I think as the original paper above suggests one needs to cite all of them! they all cover some special cases. I found [8] prop 1.5 probably contains all cases that I want, except with the assumption of working over algebraically closed field, which I think it is not essential.

Comment: I think the only reasonable notion of stability is geometrically stable, i.e. after passing to the algebraic closure.

Comment: Well for my purpose I only need semi-stability over finite field. Is there a problem with harder-narasimhan over finite fields?

Comment: No, in fact the original Harder-Narasimhan paper defines the H-N filtration over any field.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you look for is in Butler's paper [3], Theorem 1.2, where he proves semistability of the syzygy bundle for any semistable vector bundle $\cal{E}$ over a curve $C$ of slope $\mu(\cal{E})\geq 2g$, also for $g =1$. Moreover, he proves that the syzygy bundle is stable unless $C$ is hyperelliptic and $\Omega_C\hookrightarrow \cal{E}$. But he assumes the base field to be algebraically closed.

Note that one has more for $g\geq 2$: that the syzygy bundle is semistable for $d\geq 2g - {Cliff}(C)$, where ${Cliff}(C)$ is the Clifford index of the curve. This is proved in [4].